# postgres: localhost not connecting

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

My `postgreSQL.conf` looks like

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
```

and I also know that postgres is running

```
air:data postgres$ ps -aef | grep postgres
  504 16474 16473   0 11:34AM ??         0:00.00 postgres: logger process
  504 16476 16473   0 11:34AM ??         0:00.00 postgres: writer process
  504 16477 16473   0 11:34AM ??         0:00.00 postgres: wal writer process
  504 16478 16473   0 11:34AM ??         0:00.00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
  504 16479 16473   0 11:34AM ??         0:00.00 postgres: stats collector process
    0 16087 16078   0 10:54AM ttys001    0:00.03 su - postgres
  504 16473     1   0 11:34AM ttys001    0:00.22 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/postgres -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data
  504 16484 16088   0 11:34AM ttys001    0:00.00 grep postgres
```

But I am not able to connect

```
 psql -Uuser -W
Password for user user:
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Also, when I run the following

```
 lsof -i tcp:5432
 ✘ me@air11:37:13 ⮀ ~ ⮀ netstat -a | grep postgres
tcp6       0      0  *.postgres             *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.postgresql           *.*                    LISTEN
```

It says nothing running on `port 5432`
What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

My `pg_hba.conf` looks like

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Are you on a Mac OS X machine by any chance? (It's generally good to mention your platform)

Comment: My bad, yes, I am using Mac OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this was happening, but I found [postgresapp.com](http://postgresapp.com) which is pretty good to use

I am using this with http://www.pgadmin.org/ and I am running it smoothly so far

Answer (score 4):

In pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

last column change to `trust`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `psql` program that comes that the PostgreSQL package that you installed instead of the `psql` in the `/usr/bin` directory that is part of the Apple system.

For example, if using [postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/), they say in their [documentation](http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_1):

> Mac OS 10.7 ships with an older version of PostgreSQL, which can be
>   started with the following command:
>
> $ psql -h localhost PostgreSQL ships with a constellation of useful
>   binaries, like pg_dump or pg_restore, that you will likely want to
>   use. Go ahead and add the /bin directory that ships with Postgres.app
>   to your PATH (preferably in .profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, or the like to
>   make sure this gets set for every Terminal session):
>
> PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
>   Once your
>   path is correctly set up, you should be able to run psql without a
>   host. (If not, check that the correct version is being loaded in the
>   PATH by doing which psql)

If using another source of pre-packaged postgresql, it's the same thing with different paths.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to stop service and agian start the service. once you reload the configuration file. check again while it is working or not.